# Mock methods on Static Instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class as :

```
public class Factory {
   private static final Factory instance = new Factory();
   private Factory() {
   }
   public static Factory getInstance() {
       return instance;
   }
   private Client client = null;

   //To be mocked
   //Failing at this point 
   //Not actually using mocked method
   public Client getClient(Properties properties) {
      //doSomething
      //...
      return client;
   }
}
```

In another class above method is used as:

```
public class Service {
  protected Client client = null;
  protected void keySetup() {
     //Should be mocked
     client = Factory.getInstance().getClient(properties());

     ...
     ...
  }
}
```

For unit testing the keySetup() method, I am trying to mock the **Factory.getInstance().getClient(properties())** but I am failing.

I try doing the following:

```
@Test
public void testKeySetupTrue(){
    Client client = mock(Client.class); 
    Factory factory = mock(Factory.class);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(factory, "client", client);    
    Properties properties = mock(Properties.class);

    Mockito.doReturn(client).when(factory)
    .getClient(properties);

    Service service = new Service();

    service.keySetup();
    ...
    ...
}
```

When I was running in debug mode I saw it was actually executing the **getClient(Properties properties)** which was mocked.

How to resolve this?

Comment: This won't work with Mockit since this framework can not (and actually should not) mock static and final methods and/or classes

Comment: use powermockito instead

Comment: According to @MaciejKowalski 's answer you could use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) but I would not recommend you to do that since this framework modifies the bytecode so you have not your originally designed code which could lead to some unwanted/unexpected behavior. I would recommend to redesign your classes to be able to test the code.

Answer (score 1):

`static final` is not a great design.
It is better to inject the dependency and let the framework (spring or other) worry about controlling the singleton.
That said,
in your case,
use reflection to set the `Factory instance` variable with a mock Factory.

Comment: Agreed. Singletons are more trouble than they are worth most of the time, especially when it comes to testing. In this case, all the problems are home-made and should be solved via refactoring instead of throwing new tools (like PowerMock or similar) on it, especially since PowerMock only solves problems that you shouldn't have in the first place.